# primefaces 6.1 live scrolling enable scrolling only on veritical bar but not through horizontal bar

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have jsf 2.2 primefaces 6.1 live scrolling datatable. I want my datatable to scroll the records only through vertical bar. At present, horizontal scroll also getting live records. The horizontal scroll bar should not get live records. It should only be used to move left and right columns scroll. How to stop live scrolling on horizontal scroll bar. Please let me know.

```
<p:dataTable id="datatable" style="text-align:center;width:100%;height:100%;"
value="#{bean.list}" var="rec" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1"
resizableColumns="true" resizeMode="expand" emptyMessage=""
liveScroll="true"  scrollHeight="100%"  scrollable="true"
rowIndexVar="rowIdx" scrollRows="100" tableStyle="table-layout:100%;">
```

Comment: Tried if PF 6.2 'fixed' this (by having primefaces 6.1 in the title you explicitly state it is a problem of this specific version only)? Tried if not using `resizableColums` fixes this? Tried if not using `table-layout:100%` fixes this?

Comment: And you totally 100% changed this qurstion... that is not the best practice in Stackoverflow

Comment: sorry for this. I cannot change primefaces version. I have tried with resizableColums  and table-layout:100%. It did not work.

Comment: _**TRY...**_ If you cannot create a [mcve] (required anyway according to [ask]) and in it you cannot _**TRY**_ a newer version to see if things are by chance fixed in the mean time, it would require _**ME**_ to do that and that is not how stackpverflow works. Good luck with waiting and hoping for answer. Cheers